# How to demux audio and video from rtspsrc and then save to file using matroska mux?

Tags: gstreamer, rtsp, gst-launch, muxer

I have been working on an application where I use rtspsrc to gather audio and video from one network camera to another. However I can not watch the stream from the camera and thereby cant verify that the stream works as intended. To verify that the stream is correct I want to record it on a SD card and then play the file on a computer. The problem is that I want the camera to do as much of the parsing, decoding, depayloading as possible since that is the purpose of the application.

I thereby have to separate the audio and video streams by a demuxer and do the parsing, decoding etc and thereafter mux them back into a matroska file.

The video decoder has been omitted since it is not done yet for this camera.

Demux to live playback sink(works)

```
gst-launch-0.10 -v rtspsrc location="rtsp://host:pass@192.168.0.91/XXX/XXXX?resolution=1280x720&audio=1&audiocodec=g711&audiosamplerate=8000&audiobitrate=64000" latency=0 name=d d. ! rtppcmudepay ! mulawdec ! audioresample ! audioconvert ! autoaudiosink d. ! rtph264depay ! ffdec_h264 ! queue ! ffmpegcolorspace ! autovideosink
```

Multiple rtspsrc to matroska(works)

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v rtspsrc location="rtsp://host:pass@192.168.0.91/XXX/XXXX?audio=1&audiocodec=g711&audiosamplerate=8000&audiobitrate=64000" latency=0 ! rtppcmudepay ! mulawdec ! audioresample ! audioconvert ! queue ! matroskamux name=mux ! filesink location=/var/spool/storage/SD_DISK/testmovie.mkv rtspsrc location="rtsp://root:pass@192.168.0.91/axis-media/media.amp?resolution=1280x720" latency=0 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! mux.
```

Single rtspsrc to matroska(fails)

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v rtspsrc location="rtsp://host:pass@192.168.0.91/XXX/XXXX?resolution=1280x720&audio=1&audiocodec=g711&audiosamplerate=8000&audiobitrate=64000" latency=0 name=d d. ! queue ! rtppcmudepay ! mulawdec ! audioresample ! audioconvert ! queue ! matroskamux name=mux d. ! queue ! rtph264depay  ! h264parse ! queue ! mux. ! filesink location=/var/spool/storage/SD_DISK/testmoviesinglertsp.mkv
```

The last example fails with the error message

```
WARNING: erroneous pipeline: link without source element
```

Have i missunderstood the usage of matroska mux and why does the 2 above examples work but not the last?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
queue ! mux. ! filesink
```

You need to do

```
queue ! mux. mux. ! filesink
```

mux. means that gst-launch should select a pad automatically from mux. and link it. You could also specify manually a name, like mux.src. So syntactically you are missing another element/pad there to link to the other element.