# Saving webcam rtsp mpeg4 stream

Tags: gstreamer, video-capture, rtp

I'm running Windows and I'm connected to a webcam via stand-alone Video Servers.
I'm trying to save the stream to file using `gstreamer`,
with the following command:

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://10.0.0.115/?multicast/mpeg4 ! decodebin ! mpegtsmux  ! filesink location=D:\SomeDir\Somefile.mp4
```

But I get the following error:

> ERROR: from element
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0 :Internal
>   data flow error. Additional debug info: gstbasesrc.c(2943):
>   gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtsp
>   src0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0:

Any ideas why?

Comment: have you tried to add quotation marks around the url? are you sure you are not missing some parameters in url(width, height etc)? check this question for inspiration http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26180533/how-to-demux-audio-and-video-from-rtspsrc-and-then-save-to-file-using-matroska-m